# How can I print a file from the command line?

Tags: printing, ms-word

Is there a way to run a file through a print driver without opening the application?

Ex: run a .docx file, without opening word, and save it to file?

Comment: Clarification:  Are you printing to a file or a physical printer?

Comment: Please provide operating system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it is a `.docx`-file Microsoft Word is probably the best program to do the task.

I would have a look at the [command line arguments] to Word:

Have a look at the following switches:

`/q`, `/n`, `/mFilePrintDefault` and `/mFileExit`

(`/q` and `/n` explained in the page above, and `/mXxxx` refers to macros. Have a look att google.)

**Example:**

```
WINWORD.EXE your_document.docx /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit /q /n
```

The following [page](https://web.archive.org/web/20190416090459/http://winhlp.com:80/WordCommandLineSwitches.htm) seems to explain how to convert it to PDF.

Comment: I had to use `/mFileCloseOrExit` to get the Word closed.

Comment: Also, I discovered that the printing will fail if the document has outside of the printable area. Word pops up a warning and never gets to the printing. The workaround was to create a [special macro](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?710129-RESOLVED-VB6-Word-How-can-I-avoid-margin-warning-messages) SpecialPrint in Normal.dotm that suppresses this warning, and use `/mSpecialPrint` instead of `/mFilePrintDefault`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "headless start" of the program which needs to print.
I know for sure that OpenOffice can do this.
Basically, you need to start it and invoke a macro which will do the printing. Even more, you can print to a PDF, HTML, or anything else that Oo supports.

This negates the need for install of Microsoft Word and the cost of license, because OpenOffice is free.

Answer (score 0):

If

- you have problems with Macro warnings;
- you are able to modify the default printer to be PDF Printer or similar;
- and you have the ability to add or record Macros.

Add something like this to normal.dotm:

```
Sub CmdPrint()
'
' CmdPrint Macro
'
'
    Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Item:= _
     wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:= _
     wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False, _
     PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
     PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
End Sub
```

Then call from the command line as detailed above, such as:

```
@echo off & setlocal
set ProjectFolder=%USERPROFILE%\Projects
set Project=MyTest
set DocType=docm
start winword "%ProjectFolder:\\=\%%Project%.%DocType%" /q /n /mCmdPrint mFileCloseOrExit
```

Comment: VBA hasn't rendered properly...

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking only for .docx silent printing then [aioobe] answer is the best. If you want a more generic silent print program that runs on Windows, use powershell or .NET and use the print verb. http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30441939/how-to-suppress-printdialog-when-using-print-verb.aspx provides an example.

Hope this helps, if so +1 please :)

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in [DocTo](https://github.com/tobya/DocTo) which will convert a word document to another file format, including pdf and XPS but does require Word on the machine.

For example

```
Docto -f "c:\docs\mydocument.docx" -o "c:\output" -t wdFormatPDF
```

Will output mydocument.docx to c:\output\mydocument.pdf as a pdf file.